# bibliography problem large spacing

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, urls

```
@booklet{Ph4,
author = {Panchenko, D.},
title = {Statistics for Applications / Gamma Distribution},
year = {2006},
url = {http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2003/lecture-notes/lec8.pdf},
}
```

> D. Panchenko. Statistics for applications        /        gamma
>   distribution,
>   2006.                     URL http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/ 18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2003/lecture-notes/lec8.pdf.

Guys I have this problem, in my document I insert normally the following command ans I got it in my text with huge spaces, It doesn't brake the url, what can I do?

Comment: Please clarify: do you use *bibtex* -- and, if so, which bibliography style file do you employ (`plainnat` maybe?) -- or *biblatex*?

Comment: \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} and I am using bibtex

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the `url` package with the option `hyphens`. Loading this package with this option will allow line breaks to occur after hyphens in the url string. A full MWE might be (assuming the `.bib` file is named `test.bib`) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*} 
\bibliography{test} % assumes that bib file is named "test.bib"
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes the package url is loaded,I can see the URL the thing is that I have large spaces because it does not brake the url,due to Mico it is better but still the gap between URL and the address is too long,can I manage to fix by myself with \\,or something else,thank you very much

Comment: @Vangelis - please consider amending your question to provide a full MWE -- if you want, you can take the example above as a starting point -- that shows the exact line width you're working with. Without that information it's going to be well-nigh impossible to give definitive (and satisfactory) advice.